# How to define a private python path on linux like with a _pth file?

Tags: python, portable-executable, pythonpath

How to define a private python path on linux like with a _pth file?

Embedded python on windows comes with a private python path. It can be defined in a _pth file. The system pythonpath is ignored in this case. This is very useful to install python applications on servers which run additional other python applications.
Is this achievable on linux too?

PS: I use portable python builds from this website: https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone/releases

Comment: quickly looking in documentation, it look like you need to manually modify sys.path

Comment: Unfortunately, this ._pth hack is only implemented on Windows in CPython. There is a pybuilddir.txt on UNIX. But it is subtly different and I'm not convinced it is appropriate for this project to set.

by indygreg